# Creating a text file with some html tags for formatting with condition using csv file script working for 1 row but needs for all row

Tags: bash, shell, csv

Can someone please help me how to convert this in loop so that this logic will work for all row, I wants if column4 is greater then column3 then column4 will be in red colour same txt file I will use in email body so that highlight will be visible there

**Input Csv file having data**
[image: input csv data]

```
App Launch Time,    Login Page, 7091,   8091
Page Load Time,     Home Page,  303,    993
Page Api Response,  Home Page,  861,    761
Page Parsing Time,  Home Page,  141,    221
```

**Using below shell script**

```
a=`awk -F',' '{print $1}' 'input.csv'`
b=`awk -F',' '{print $2}' 'input.csv'`
c=`awk -F',' '{print $3}' 'input.csv'`
d=`awk -F',' '{print $4}' 'input.csv'`
if [ $d -gt $c ]
then
echo '<tr>' '<td align="center">'$a'</td>' '<td align="center">'$b'</td>' '<td align="center">'$c'</td>' '<td align="center" bgcolor="red">'$d'</td>' '</tr>' >> compare.txt
else
echo '<tr>' '<td align="center">'$a'</td>' '<td align="center">'$b'</td>' '<td align="center">'$c'</td>' '<td align="center">'$d'</td>' '</tr>' >> compare.txt
fi
echo '</table>' >> compare.txt
```

**Output like this in txt file - Below output of 1 row require same for all row**

```
<tr> <td align="center">AppLaunchTime</td> <td align="center">LoginPage</td> <td align="center">7091</td> <td align="center" bgcolor="red">8091</td> </tr>
```

Comment: Please help !! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F', *' '
    BEGIN{ print "<table>" }
    {
        printf "<tr>"
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){
            printf("<td align=\"center\"%s>%s</td>", (i==4 && $4>$3 ? " bgcolor=\"red\"": ""), $i)
        }
        print "</tr>"
    }
    END{ print "</table>" }
' input.csv > compare.txt

$ cat compare.txt 
<table>
<tr><td align="center">App Launch Time</td><td align="center">Login Page</td><td align="center">7091</td><td align="center" bgcolor="red">8091</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">Page Load Time</td><td align="center">Home Page</td><td align="center">303</td><td align="center" bgcolor="red">993</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">Page Api Response</td><td align="center">Home Page</td><td align="center">861</td><td align="center">761</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">Page Parsing Time</td><td align="center">Home Page</td><td align="center">141</td><td align="center" bgcolor="red">221</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```
while IFS=, read -r a b c d; do     
    if [ $d -gt $c ]
    then
        echo '<tr>' '<td align="center">'$a'</td>' '<td align="center">'$b'</td>' '<td align="center">'$c'</td>' '<td align="center" bgcolor="red">'$d'</td>' '</tr>' >> compare.txt
    else
        echo '<tr>' '<td align="center">'$a'</td>' '<td align="center">'$b'</td>' '<td align="center">'$c'</td>' '<td align="center">'$d'</td>' '</tr>' >> compare.txt
    fi     
 done < input.csv
echo '</table>' >> compare.txt
```

Comment: Same but using printf reusing and static strings `while...
red=''
if [ "$d" -gt "$c" ]; then
    red='bgcolor="red"'
fi
printf '<tr> <td align="center">%d</td> <td align="center">%d</td> <td align="center">%d</td> <td align="center" %s>%d</td> </tr>' a b c red d

done < input.csv >> compare.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Using just 1 `awk`

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN {fmt="<tr><td align="center">%s</td><td align=\"center\">%s</td><td align=\"center\">%s</td><td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"%s\">%s</td></tr>"}

{color=($4>$3)?"red":"black"; printf(fmt, $1, $2, $3, color, $4)} 

END {printf("</table>\n")}' input.csv
```